# Display query string in asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing an ASP web application with VB back-end. What I'd like to do is generate a url and display this in control on the page. For example if I have a label and a button on the form. The label is blank. When the button is clicked the following code fires:

```
 Protected Sub btnGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    label1.Text = "Hello"
End Sub
```

What I'd like to have is a url that would point to my ASP Page with the words "Hello" in the label. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the text in query string e.g. suppose relative path of the page is /pagename.aspx , you can pass the query string as per given example below:

```
/pagename.aspx?text=hello
```

in c# write following code in Page_Load event

```
//You don't have to check the url all the time , so just check it if page is not posting back (first time after user visits the page and ignore all other same page post backs. Label can maintain its control state (text value) after every postback, so assign it only once to increase performance
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Check if query string is provided or not , if it is not provided take some default text, I am taking empty string as default text.
    string givenText = (Request.QueryString["text"] == null)?"":Request.QueryString["text"];
    label1.Text = givenText;
}
```

You can also create a property for text given through query string and default text.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
{siteaddress}/aspxpage.aspx?label=hello
```

then in you aspx page do something like:

```
<asp:label runat="server" id="yourLabelId" text='<%=Request.QueryString("label")%>' />
```

Or in the Page_Load:

```
yourLabelId.Text = Request.QueryString("label")
```

I would recommend validating the data before just writing it into the page.

Comment: If I use this. And I am not doing a POSTBACK, i.e. the individual is using the application as normal, will it still look for "label" in the query string?